# Python regex conditional, don't match if

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Sorry for the somewhat unhelpful title, I'm having a really hard time explaining this issue.

I have a list of unique identifiers that can appear in a number of different ways and I'm trying to use regex to normalize them so I can compare across several databases. Here are some examples of them:

```
AB1201
AB-1201
AB1201-T
AB-12-01L1
AB1201-TER
AB1201 Transit
```

I've written a line of code that pulls out all hypens and spaces, and the used this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{4})(L\d|Transit|T$)?
```

This works exactly as expected, returning a list looking like this:

```
AB1201
AB1201
AB1201T
AB1201L1
AB1201
AB1201T
```

The issue is, I have one identifier that looks like this: `AB1201-02`. I need this to be raised as an exception, and not included as a match.

Any ideas? I'm happy to provide more clarification if necessary. Thanks!

[From Regex101 online tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBk1v.png)

Comment: Add start and end of string anchors to your regex i.e. `^([a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{4})(L\d|Transit|T$)?$`

Comment: I tried that, it dropped the match completely for AB1201-TER, in this case I need to match as AB1201 (because in this case TER is just an extra code that isn't always used in every database). It could also be AB1201-EFH or AB1201-GNS etc.

Comment: Can you include those codes (e.g. `-[A-Z]{3}`) into your last alternation?

Comment: Do you mean like this? ^([a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{4})(L\d|Transit|T$|-[A-Z]{3})?$         In that case AB1201-TER is retained entirely but AB1201EFH and is ignored entirely. But AB1201-02 is also ignored entirely so that's a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude matching the following hyphen and a digit `(?!-\d)` using a negative lookahead.

If it should start at the beginning of the string, you could use an anchor `^`

Note that you could write `[\d]` as `\d`

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4})(?!-\d)(L\d|Transit|T$)?
```

The pattern will look like

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}` Match 2 times a-zA-Z and 4 digits
- `)` Close group
- `(?!-\d)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not `-` and a digit
- `(L\d|Transit|T$)?` Optional capture **group 2**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zodEor/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{4})(?!-\d)(L\d|Transit|T|-[A-Z]{3})?$
```

I have added the `(?!...) Negative Lookahead` to avoid matching with the `-02`.

> (?!...) Negative Lookahead: Starting at the current position in the expression, ensures that the given pattern will not match. Does not consume characters.

You can view a demo on [this](https://regex101.com/r/KYLUPX/3) link.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the match to fail elsewhere where I need it to match. AB1201-EFH does not match at all, but it should match as AB1201. Also, the -02 exception is just one example, but I foresee something similar happening again so I'm hesitant to hard code against one specific example.

Comment: Describe the corner cases a little better and add some more data, if possible, so we can make this work.

Comment: I added an image above to my original post with a screen grab from Regex101, hopefully this helps. The thing is, I don't know all the edge cases for sure right, because I haven't run this yet on the full database, but I am trying to work under the assumption that something else like AB1201-02 or AB12-01-02 etc could come up.